# mysql restore to different database

Tags: mysql

I back up my production database with the following command:

```
mysqldump -u root --opt --skip-extended-insert --databases my_production_db
```

The resulting dump file has the following lines near the top:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `my_production_db` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `my_production_db `;
```

In order to restore the database to a different destination ie. `my_debvelopment_db` I have to open the dump file and edit the bits where the database is named.

Then I run:

```
mysql -u root  -p <password> < mydumpfile
```

I have not figured out another way to do it.

As the database gets bigger this becomes impractical.

Am I missing something? Cant I somehow specify where I want to restore the database? Would I need a different backup command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you drop the option `--databases` but still specify the database name, you will NOT get the create database statements. ie:

```
mysqldump -u root --opt --skip-extended-insert  my_production_db
```

On your dev machine simply create any database you wish to restore to.

Comment: Even without a `--databases` option, seems `mysqldump` still may generate reference to a database name in the dump. At least I get issue with some `ALTER DATABASE \`dbname\` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin` in a database dump, while not using the `--databases` option. And there was two of these, the second overriding the first.

Answer (score 59):

@minaz answer was good, but I want to append a little bit more.

The problem was caused by `--databases` keyword. If you omit the keyword, it will not contain any database creation contents.

So, Dump without `--databases` keyword.

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > dump.sql
```

And restore it with the target database name.

```
mysql -u username -p target_database_name < dump.sql
```

Also, there are several ways to do this. See the similar problem on [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/restore-mysql-database-with-different-name) (dba.stackexchange).

Comment: I believe there is an error with `-p database_name`, as the `-p` option name is the short name for the `--password` option.

Comment: @Hibou57 Thanks for comment. Yes, `-p` means `--password` as you mentioned. But `-p` actually means 'I will put my password via prompt'. If you want to put password via command option, there should be no blank(space) like `-p<your_password>` not `-p <your_password>`.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password

Comment: Expressing ```--databases``` switch in `mysql` command solve my issue in creating separate dump for each database and restore them one by one in another server. Thanks!

Comment: Here is my code snippet to dump and restore.
[mostly based on Mattias Geniar blog](https://ma.ttias.be/mysql-back-up-take-a-mysqldump-with-each-database-in-its-own-sql-file/)

1. Generate backup with `mysqldump` command.

```DATE=`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M`
mariadb -N -e 'show databases' | while read dbname; do mariadb-dump --complete-insert --routines --triggers --single-transaction --databases "$dbname" | gzip -c  > "$dbname"_"$DATE".sql.gz ; done```

2. Restore with maridb command. here as we place table creation commands inside sqldump file.
```$ mariadb -u user < SQL_dump_file.sql```

Answer (score 4):

On windows xampp I used following commands to achieve this

Export

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydb > mydb.sql
```

Import

```
mysql -u root -p mynewdb < mydb.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for to simply clone a db to another. Create the db schema first then rum these commands.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have your dump you can strip the commands for creating and using the database. Simply remove the fourth and the new fifth line.

```
sed '4d' dump.sql | sed '5d' > dump-striped.sql
```

Comment: Is better to just show the lines to remove. There are only two. Method you give is arbitrary - especially if format changes or has other manual edits..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it was created with `--databases`

You can use the following sed script.

```bash
sed -n '/-- Current Database:/,/-- Table structure for table /!p' dump.sql
```

This assumes that the database creation and switch is written as follows

```sql
--
-- Current Database: `mydatabase`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mydatabase` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */;

USE `mydatabase`;

--
-- Table structure for table `myfirsttable`
--
```

So this will strip out everything in between that block of text in the dump file.