# mysql database restore to another database

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I have many old database backup and sometime I want old bills and files so I created a new DB with name old_db. When I want any bills or report of any particular financial year than I upload that particular data by :-

> mysql -uroot  -p < opFilePath

but this is not working because when I open sql file, that file has the following lines:-

> CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `gha_1314` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

I have got one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015474/mysql-restore-to-different-database) but I already have many db and db is also very large.

I don't know how to figure out from this problem ? Is there any way to import this db without remove this (CREATE DATABASE `gha_1314` ) ?

Please suggest me and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Not really, no. What's wrong with just removing that line?

Comment: data is very large that is the problem

Comment: It's one line in one file, no? Or you mean you have lots of files where you have this line? You could write a command line script or other batch program to find/replace this line in multiple files. How exactly you do this will depend on your operating system. With Linux/Unix/Mac it's fairly easy using grep and regular expressions.

Comment: In Linux/Unix, I would delete the first line (if it is the first line) using the sed command: sed '1d' filename.sql

Comment: Or to comment the line: sed 's|CREATE DATABASE.*gha_1314|/*\0*/|' filename.sql

Comment: @ADyson Yes its is one line in one file but I have lots of files where I have this line and some data files are more than 1GB. My OS is Centos.

Comment: The size of the files does not matter much, apart from it might take a bit longer for a script to process them and find the line to remove in each one. But it's a one time task so that's not really a big problem.