# Import database with .frm and .ibd directly from the folders

Tags: mysql

hi I have my database with the different folder in .frm and .ibd, I inserted this documents into current database folder that it is in var/lib/mysql/current_database the thing or the issue is that if I go to phpmyadmin and then I refresh to see if that new tables that I added before where uploaded, they will not display at all.

and this new table that I added is in same path where visible tables in phpmyadmin are.. example:

I can see users table but If I add rols table I do not see it even if it is same path so I wonder what can I do to fix it? what do I need to do to see in phpmyadmin or mysql database that new table that I added in var/lib/mysql/current_database

Thanks

Comment: Moving files (like .frm or .idb) is NOT the way to deal with MySQL, and can destroy your database.

Comment: Moving tables from one database to another: [mysql restore to different database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015474/mysql-restore-to-different-database)